# how to dynamically add property for a html tag based on some condition in angular 4 using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I want to add the property of mat-accordion "displayMode" based on the value given for a variable in app component.

I am using ng-if to make it. But Im getting error.

```
<mat-accordion class="accord-align" *ngIf="displayType" then displayMode="{{displayType}}" ><br/>
<<Some tags and text here>><br/>
</mat-accordion&gt;<br/>
```

If I provide like this *ngIf="displayType" then displayMode="{{displayType}}", then its showing error saying

```
compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:<><br/>
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 30 in [displayType then displayMode={{displayType}}] in ng:///AppModule/AccordionComponent.html@1:38 ("&lt;div id="divi-align"&gt; <br/>
  &lt;mat-accordion class="accord-align" [ERROR -&gt;]*ngIf="displayType then displayMode={{displayType}}" &gt;
    &lt;mat-expansion-panel  class="panel1-align""): ng:///AppModule/AccordionComponent.html@1:38<br/>
Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-accordion'.<br/>
1. If 'mat-accordion' is an Angular component and it has '*ngIf' input, then verify that it is part of this module.<br/>
2. If 'mat-accordion' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.<br/>
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("&lt;div id="divi-align"&gt;
  &lt;mat-accordion class="accord-align" [ERROR -&gt;]*ngIf="displayType then displayMode={{displayType}}" &gt;
    &lt;mat-expansion-panel  class="panel1-align""): ng:///AppModule/AccordionComponent.html@1:38<br/>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using **then** here: `*ngIf="displayType then displayMode={{displayType}}"`? This HTML is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for responding.
Here displayType is a variable defined in app component. If its value is not null then I want to add the property displayMode with the interpolated value of displayType. Otherwise I will not add that property itself.

Answer (score 7):

You can't use `*ngIf` to add/remove attributes, only to add/remove elements.

I assume this is what you're looking for:

```
[attr.displayMode]="displayType ? displayType : null"
```

`attr.` ensures that it is actually added to the DOM instead of only passed to a components class instance.

Passing `null` removes the attribute from the element.

Comment: When I see your answers, I know that you are right without reading it ;)

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, then probably yes ;-)

Comment: The question is not mine, I'm another one user :). I just know that you're well experienced in Angular, because very often I see your answers, and they are pretty good.

Comment: Actually I can give 2 values for displayMode i.e., flat and gutter. Gutter is default value. After adding '[attr.displayMode]="displayType ? displayType : null" ', even If I give displayType value as flat but its taking value as gutter

Comment: @CommercialSuicide uh, sorry, didn't check the user name. Thanks for the kind words!

Comment: @ShreelakshmiG that's different. I don't know what your expected behavior is. Perhaps you want just `[attr.displayMode]="displayType"`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much @GünterZöchbauer